# How to get accessToken generated whit passport in loopback

Tags: passport.js, loopbackjs, loopback, passport-facebook

I am integrating passport with loopback, and works fine, the problems is how to get the access token.

I have a web app (served in a different server than loopback) so:

1. Make the request (in the loopback backend)
2. This redirect me to Facebook, approve it
3. Return to loopback (do the passport work)
4. Now, how can i get the accessToken generated in my web app?

I can redirect (if login is successful) to my web app, but i lose the accessToken in the progress.

Any ideas?

i make the request

### SOLUTION:

The access token is seted by loopback in the cookies, so when redirect back to the web app, can access by:

```
 document.cookie
```

if you wanna pass through a variable:

```
var access_token = document.cookie.replace(/(?:(?:^|.*;\s*)access_token\s*\=\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$/, "$1")
var userId = document.cookie.replace(/(?:(?:^|.*;\s*)userId\s*\=\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$/, "$1")
```

### BUT

if you use different URLs for the backend and the frontend, you cant
so i recommend use the solution of this post

Comment: I'm glad that you found the solution by yourself, it is very helpful, but could you post that part as an answer, instead of editing your questions? That is how it should be done at Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope, I got the idea. Here is the flow I follow with passport/facebook strategy. 
1) Client side(web app): `window.location = http://urlServerName:port/passport/facebook`
This can be a redirect on server side also.
2) User enter credentials on facebook.
3) Facebook redirect to callback.

```
router.get('/passport/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook'));
router.get('/passport/facebook/callback', passport.authenticate('facebook', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
   (req, res) => {

      let url = req.url; // url contains the code
      let urs = req.usr; // user info.
      // You can set a cookie with the info you want. This can be the auth code, the user profile or a JWT generated in the same request.
      res.cookie("data",usr,{httpOnly:true});            
      res.redirect('urlWebApplication');          
});
```

4) Inside your callback you can set a cookie with the information you want. This way it can be access in your webapp.
Hope this help to clarify.

Comment: Thanks for your solution Hosar, i found a easier way, but this work with different urls